# rdf_loader_run stuck and Virtuoso server doesn't respond to queries

Tags: virtuoso

I've run these commands:

```
ld_add('/path/datasets/dbpedia/2015-04/dbpedia_2015-04.owl', 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/classes#');
rdf_loader_run();
ld_dir_all('/path/datasets/dbpedia/2015-04/importedGraphs/dbpedia.org', '*.*', 'http://dbpedia.org');
```

That all ran successfully, but then I ran:

```
rdf_loader_run();
```

It's been 48 hours on a CoreI7 machine with 24GB ram, Virtuoso server is not using any CPU, and it doesn't respond to queries such as:

```
select * from DB.DBA.LOAD_LIST;
```

...in another instances of `isql-vt`. The size of files in `/var/lib/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/db/` are not increasing.

Comment: You don't say what version of Virtuoso is in use, but it appears to be a long-outdated Open Source Edition v6.1. I suggest updating to [current VOS, 7.2.2](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews). You don't say what guide you're following; I'd suggest [this one](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoaderExampleDbpedia).

Comment: Virtuoso-specific and non-programming questions are often better raised to Virtuoso-specific resources, e.g., [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [public OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or a [confidential OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).

Comment: Yeah the problem was running old version of virtuoso, I've upgraded virtuoso and it finished all imports in 14 hours.

Comment: @TallTed will do from now on, should I delete this one?

Comment: I'd say either delete, or rewrite such that it might lead someone else with the same problem to the same successful resolution -- i.e., updating to current software.

Comment: @TallTed I added the required info to solve this in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using an old version of virtuoso, by upgrading to 7.2 as suggested in comments it solved. I didn't have this problem on my macbook, so seems that while homebrew installs latest version by default, apt-get doesn't do so in Ubuntu and you need to install the latest version.

Comment: Now I see why you were having issues...  Third-party packaging (as in `apt-get`, `homebrew`, and others) is often outdated upon delivery.  We do provide [guidance for building from latest source on Ubuntu](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSUbuntuNotes).

Comment: I got [the link from a live page](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSUbuntuNotes), and have just retested; it's fine. I'd guess you hit some intermittent network issue.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it's working now, it just didn't work at the time neither on my machine nor my remote machines in usa. I guess it was a temporary problem. Thanks for this helpful guide.